# accessing the data from another model in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models named Subject & Page. there is one to many association between them.

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :pages
  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessible :position
  attr_accessible :visible
  attr_accessible :created_at
end
```

and

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :subject                                                    
   attr_accessible :subject_id
   attr_accessible :name
   attr_accessible :permalink
   attr_accessible :position
   attr_accessible :visible
   attr_accessible :created_at
end
```

I have list.html.erb in view -> pages folder.

Q. My qus is I want to show all the subject_id in list.html.erb. how?
for that which changes I have to do in pages_controller & list.html.erb so that I will got solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any Model in any Controller in following way

```
   @instance_variable = ModelClass.all
```

In your case it should be something like following

pages_controller.rb

```
def list 
  @subjects_list = Subject.all
end
```

app/views/pages/list.html.erb

```
<% for subject in @subjects_list %>
  <!--  Your Code Here  -->
<% end %>
```